# Deployment of azure policy definitions to management group permissions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-policy

Im trying to deploy some policy definitions to a management group, however im getting authorization errors.

I doing it through Azure devops running a azure powershell script taking advantage of the New-AzPolicyDefinition -ManagementGroupName cmdlet.

This pipeline is configured with a service connection to a service principal, currently with Resource Policy Contributor, but i've tried with Management group contributor, Contributor and owner as well

Anyone knows why im not allowed to do this and what kind of permissions is needed?

Thanks

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being i had a different management group ID than my management group name. The cmdlets are asking for the ID and not name after confirming this with microsoft this was solved and confirmed it was lacking clarity in their documentation and something they are aware of

Answer (score 0):

For the write access for management group scope, you will need RBAC role as: Owner, Contributor, Management Group Contributor to the target management group.

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/manage#moving-management-groups-and-subscriptions) documentation.

Make sure you use the **actual name** and not the **"DisplayName"** of the management group.

Comment: Do i need both of these roles to be able to perform a deployment of the policy definitions to a management group scope?

I have given it owner and the other mentioned roles individually on the management group without any luck

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue:`##[error]AuthorizationFailed : The client '***' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/policydefinitions/write' over scope '***' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.`

It works on my side and here are my steps:

1.Create management group:

[image]

2.Create service connection and click Manage Service Principal option in the Azure DevOps service connection:

[image]

3.Copy the display name(My value looks like OrgName-ProjectName-SubscriptionID. I found yours is a little different mine):
[image]

4.Add role assignment(Owner or Resource Policy Contributor) for the display name in the management group. I can find two results here and I added them both:
[image]

5.Here is my configuration of Azure Pipeline:
[image]

Comment: I have configured that service principals with the roles mentioned, Contributor, Owner, Resource Policy Contributor and Management group contributor.

None of these rules allows me to run the deployment, even if these are set on the root on the management group tree im doing into

Comment: @MathiasWrobel When I search the display name in the role assignment, I find two results and I add both of them. You can assign Owner or Resource Policy Contributor role. They works on my side. Can you share a screenshot of your role assignment if you still have this issue? In addition, are the authorization errors you mentioned the same as mine?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11utueb
Yes the error is the same.
Currently it's configured with the resource policy contributor as you can see in the picture, but i've tried with owner and such as well

##[error]AuthorizationFailed : The client 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/policydefinitions/write' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MLZ/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policydefinitions/

Comment: @MathiasWrobel I can find two results when I search my service principal in role assignment. If I only add one of them, I will still have the issue. Please try to create a new service connection in Azure DevOps and try again.

Comment: i've now set it with Owner and Resource Policy Contributor simultaneous and then recreated the service connection. Still not working

Comment: @MathiasWrobel I updated my all steps to answer. By the way, how did you create your service connection? I'm using Azure Resource Manager using service principal (automatic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231458/discussion-between-mathias-wrobel-and-walter-qian-msft).